# Using try_files with uwsgi

Tags: nginx, flask, react-router, uwsgi

I am trying to use the nginx `try_files` directive with `uwsgi_pass` and having a ton of difficulty.

Basically what I want is for `try_files` to ask the uWSGI container if the request URI is valid and if not, then serve up the index.html file instead.  My nginx config is as follows:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   access_log /tmp/nginx.log;

   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
       include uwsgi_params;
       uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:5001;
   }
}
```

But what this does is check the docroot for every request and if its not there, it simply bails and returns the index.html file.

What I want instead is the following:

1. Request comes in for www.myapp.com
2. nginx forwards this request onto the uWSGI container
3. If that is invalid, then return the index.html

Is there a way to 'ask' uWSGI to try the files instead?

What I'm ultimately trying to accomplish here is HTML5 Pushstate with React Router.  I'm running a Flask app with a React front-end.  If the user refreshes the browser at `www.myapp.com/preferences/useri`d, then I want nginx to forward that to the container and if its invalid, to return the index.

Comment: cant you use a separate path for the requests handled by uwsgi (use 2 locations / always returns index html. /api always passes onto uwsgi)

Comment: @Chamindu I tried that already, but the problem is that my index.html file is served by uWSGI also.  But maybe this is the source of my problem...

Comment: I think its best to let nginx serve static files and let uwsgi worry about dynamic content.

Answer (score 1):

So, after talking with @Chamindu, I realized I was probably going about this the wrong way.  I prevented uWSGI from serving my index.html (even though it could) and instead relied on nginx to serve that instead.

```
server {
   listen 80;
   access_log /tmp/nginx.log;

   location / {
       root /var/www/myapplication/;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   }

   location /api {
       include uwsgi_params;
       uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:5001;
   }
}
```